# Endless loop and segfault when passing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to write Mergesort in C++.

I have two functions so far, the MergeSort function which takes the input and calls the split function on it.

```
void Split(const std::vector<int>& input, std::vector<int>* output1, std::vector<int>* output2) {



    std::cout << "In split function" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << input[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (input.size() > 1) {


        int i = 0;
        int j = input.size() - 1;

        while (i < j) {
            output1->push_back(input[i]);
            i++;


            output2->push_back(input[j]);
            j--;
        }



        std::vector<int> left= {};
        std::vector<int> right = {};
        std::vector<int> *left_ptr = &left;
        std::vector<int> *right_ptr = &right;

        Split(*output1, left_ptr, right_ptr);
        Split(*output2, left_ptr, right_ptr);
    }
}

void MergeSort(std::vector<int>* input){
    std::vector<int> output1= {};
    std::vector<int> output2 = {};
    std::vector<int> *ptr1 = &output1;
    std::vector<int> *ptr2 = &output2;
    std::cout << "Starting mergesort" << std::endl;
    Split(*input, ptr1, ptr2);

}
```

I also have a Merge function that I haven't included.

As you can see, I create two lists that the initial list will split into. I then pass the pointers to these lists into the split function.

I know there are easier ways to do this, but this is a homework assignment, so the function signatures have to remain as they are.

Here is a part of the output I get with this code:

```
In split function
3, 4, 
In split function
3, 
In split function
4, 
In split function
1, 2, 
In split function
3, 1, 
In split function
3, 
In split function
1, 
In split function
4, 2,
```

This goes on endlessly.

I then changed the code a little bit. Instead of the having pointers that pointed to address spaces, I just made the pointers directly.

For example, here's what I did to the mergesort function:

```
void MergeSort(std::vector<int>* input){
    std::vector<int> *output1= {};
    std::vector<int> *output2 = {};
    std::cout << "Starting mergesort" << std::endl;
    Split(*input, output1, output2);
}
```

Now the output I get is this:

```
Starting mergesort
In split function
3, 5, 1, 2, 9, 4, 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is the difference between these two implementations? What is going on in each? How do I make this work?

Comment: There is no need for pointers at all if you're writing a merge sort using vectors.  Any decent implementation would pass references, not pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand, but since this is a homework assignment with explicit instructions to do it this way, I'm stuck :(

Comment: You call `Split` twice, both calls pushing into the same pair of vectors, `left` and `right`. The second call adds more values to the result of the first call, and then calls `Split` recursively again. Therefore, the two `output` vectors would always contain at least two values (one from each call), and the recursion never stops.

Comment: Also, if `input` contains an odd number of elements, you lose the middle one in the `while (i < j)` loop.

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thank you for pointing that out @IgorTandetnik